# How to use javascript function for multiple tasks?

Tags: javascript, html

i have javascript function. 
i am using that function to translate english language to another language in a text field. 
as below form when a person type in box01, box02 shows typed english content in translated mode.

```
 <form id="txtBox" action="ps.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

 <textarea  id="box01" onkeyup="startText_sin();" onselect="startText_sin();" onclick="startText_sin();" rows="2" placeholder ="Type in Here"></textarea>

 <textarea  id="box02" rows="2" placeholder ="Translated"></textarea>

 </form>
```

but **i have few of these forms in my single page** and the text areas have diffrent names, like bellow,

```
 <textarea  id="txt_sin01"></textarea>
 <textarea  id="txt_trn02"></textarea>
```

how can i can set function to be work with all of these text areas ?
my function is `**startText_sin()**`

in function i choose text area like this `text = document.getElementById("box01");`

any help.

__*_*___*function****_*__*_*__*_*_**

`
//array goes here

function startText_sin() {

```
var s,r,v;
//text = document.txtBox.box1.value;
text_singlish = document.getElementById("box1_singlish").value;
//special consonents
for (var i=0; i<specialConsonants.length; i++){
    text_singlish = text_singlish.replace(specialConsonants[i], specialConsonantsUni[i]);
}
//consonents + special Chars
for (var i=0; i<specialCharUni.length; i++){
    for (var j=0;j<consonants.length;j++){
        s = consonants[j] + specialChar[i];
        v = consonantsUni[j] + specialCharUni[i];
        r = new RegExp(s, "g");
        text_singlish = text_singlish.replace(r, v);
    }
}
//consonants + Rakaransha + vowel modifiers
for (var j=0;j<consonants.length;j++){
    for (var i=0;i<vowels.length;i++){
        s = consonants[j] + "r" + vowels[i];
        v = consonantsUni[j] + "්‍ර" + vowelModifiersUni[i];
        r = new RegExp(s, "g");
        text_singlish = text_singlish.replace(r, v);
    }
    s = consonants[j] + "r";
    v = consonantsUni[j] + "්‍ර";
    r = new RegExp(s, "g");
    text_singlish = text_singlish.replace(r, v);
}
//consonents + vowel modifiers
for (var i=0;i<consonants.length;i++){
    for (var j=0;j<nVowels;j++){ 
        s = consonants[i]+vowels[j];
        v = consonantsUni[i] + vowelModifiersUni[j];
        r = new RegExp(s, "g");
        text_singlish = text_singlish.replace(r, v);
    }
}

//consonents + HAL
for (var i=0; i<consonants.length; i++){
    r = new RegExp(consonants[i], "g");
    text_singlish = text_singlish.replace(r, consonantsUni[i]+"්");
}

//vowels
for (var i=0; i<vowels.length; i++){
    r = new RegExp(vowels[i], "g");
    text_singlish = text_singlish.replace(r, vowelsUni[i]);
}

document.getElementById("box2_singlish").value=text_singlish; //wirte on page in sihala
```

}

`

Comment: @oGeez check the code, i updated

Comment: To be honest, we don't really need to see the function :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the id of the textarea into the function

```
var startText_sin = function (textId) {
    text = document.getElementById(textId);
    // do stuff
};
```

And the call:

```
startText_sin("box01");
```

And an example doing it inline:

```
<textarea  id="box01" onkeyup="startText_sin("box01");" onselect="startText_sin("box01");" onclick="startText_sin("box01");" rows="2" placeholder ="Type in Here"></textarea>
```

I must say though, this is a horrible way to write a piece of software. Rather than using onselect and onclick for each individual element you can watch for events on the page and process them. I understand that **this isn't where you are at** but in the future, and for anyone reading this. If you are writing anything more complex than this then you shouldn't be using these methods.

Comment: please can you tell me how to do that, in breef ?